# Trying to get property 'user' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

> Trying to get property 'user' of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'user' of non-object at /home/brooklyn/Sistema/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php:117)

La linea es la siguiente:

```
auth()->login($social_profile->user);
```

Está mal utilizar el auth() de esta forma? existe un USE o otra forma de hacer esto?

Intento el registro con socialite

$social_profile = SocialProfile::where('social_id', $userSocialite->getId())
->where('social_name', $driver)->first();

```
if(!$social_profile){

    $user = User::where('email', $userSocialite->getEmail())->first();
    if(!$user){
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $userSocialite->user['given_name'],
            'apellido' => $userSocialite->user['family_name'],
            'email' => $userSocialite->getEmail(),
            'permiso' => 'USUARIO',
            'tipo_usuario' => 'PARTICULAR'
        ]);
    }

    SocialProfile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'social_id' => $userSocialite->getId(),
        'social_name' => $driver,
        'social_avatar' => $userSocialite->getAvatar()
    ]);

}

auth()->login($social_profile->user);

return redirect()->route('panel');
```

Comment: Si hago lo siguiente dd($social_profile); lo recibo null

Comment: recibo el siguiente error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found lo hice así: Auth::user()->login($social_profile->user);

Comment: Si en localhost me funciona perfecto esto en producción no. Ahora agregue el use Auth; y recibo el siguiente problema Call to a member function login() on null

Comment: Habrá otra manera de redireccionar al usuario logueado?

Comment: Debes tener cuidado con una cosa, te falta asignar el registro creado a la variable que estás usando `$social_profile = SocialProfile::create([....]);` cuando no encuentre un registro y entre al if.

Comment: @L.Flor graciassssss!!!! cambié esto y todo funciona perfecto! aun no entiendo que hizo que esto cambie pero ya lo voy a analizar...encontré una solución al socialite que voy a publicar en la otra respuesta para el que tenga el mismo problema...llevo días con esto! gracias y más gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber cual es el usuario que esta autenticado debes usarlo asi
$user = Auth::user(); sin embargo no se exactamente que es lo que quieres lograr. Pero eso te puede ayudar.